# Mechanical Turk uploading more hits than needed

Tags: mechanicalturk

I am new to `Mechanical Turk` and am running a survey on an external website. My task allows one worker to do 10 different HITs independently (watch 10 different movies, then be asked questions after watching the movie).

My input file has the first line with the field heading 'moviename'. The subsequent rows are the list of movies.

```
moviename 
movie_1
movie_2
...
movie_10
```

When I upload my task on sandbox from terminal, I get a return message saying that I've uploaded 11 Hits, when I only have 10 Hits. I have an annotation parameter of `videoId` which then calls upon info from my input file.

https://mywebsite.html?videoId=${moviename}

I'm assuming that `mturk` is thinking that the field heading in my input file is a HIT. Does anyone know how to fix this and have an explanation for why this is happening?

Comment: Is your CSV malformed?